# optimizing distinct query on a column with 1billion data

Tags: query-optimization, amazon-redshift

I have a temp table with 1 billion records. The sort key is on the same column that I am doing distinct on.

```
select distinct column_name from table_name
```

It's taking more than 2 mins.

Is there a way to reduce this?

Comment: break it apart into smaller chunks

Comment: the problem is this query is a subquery - part of huge query

Comment: Perhaps more information about the whole query would help us to suggest something. Is the temp table size a result of a cross-join?

Comment: yes. the temp table is a cross join of multiple tables and one of the table that it joins to create the temp table is the subquery (select distinct) and this table doesn't have primary key nor sort key. the table is a two column table.

Comment: to be more precise: table A has 1B record and it has a primary key, and other columns. i need to get all the data based on a date range.
table  A has column: primarykey, date and other columns

distkey:col2
sortkey: key in the select with interleaved

query: select primarykey, col 1, col 2, date where date >= min_date and date <=max_date

this query takes more than a minute and we want to reduce it.

any help is appreciated